# wp login password reset

Tags: login

I have forgotten my login to my wp site so have asked to reset it, however in the email that is sent for me to change my password there is no link to click to reset the password?

Answer (score 0):

****RESETTING THE ADMINISTRATOR PASSWORD IN THE DATABASE****

1] Log in to cPanel

2]In the Databases section of the cPanel home screen, click phpMyAdmin.

3]In the left-hand pane of phpMyAdmin, click the WordPress database. A list of tables in the database appears.

4]On the top menu bar, click SQL.

5]Copy and paste the following statement into the SQL query text box. Replace new_password with the new password, and replace admin_username with the administrator's username.

```
UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_pass` = MD5( 'new_password' ) WHERE `wp_users`.`user_login` = "admin_username";
```

please check codex link :https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

**Changing your WordPress password via FTP**

If you don't have access to your WordPress database, you can also reset you password with FTP.

1 ] Login to your website via FTP and navigate to your theme's functions.php file and download it to your local computer.
In my case this was /home/userna5/public_html/wp-content/themes/your_theme/functions.php

2] On line 2, right after the first

```
**wp_set_password('password','admin');**
```

In this example, we're setting the password to password, and we're updating it for the user admin, if your admin user has a different username you'll want to be sure to use that.

You'll also want to make sure that you're using a secure WordPress password.

3] Upload this modified functions.php file back to your /themes folder on the server.

4] Login to your WordPress dashboard using the new temporary password you just set.
Now that you've successfully reset your password, remove the wp_set_password line from your local functions.php file, and re-upload it. 
This way WordPress doesn't reset the password every single time the admin dashboard is accessed going forward.